# How to configure DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE on macOS

Tags: python, django

Django: 2.2.4
macOS: Mojave 10.14.5

Hello

I am having difficulty setting up Django, and in particular trying to run the server on a fresh install.

Here are the steps I have taken.

```
// Create and a enter into a new directory
mkdir mysite && cd mysite

// Create a virtual environment and activate it
virtualenv venv -p python3
source venv/bin/activate

// Install Django
pip install Django

// Create a new django project
django-admin startproject mysite .


// Run the server
django-admin runserver
```

And from there this is the error message...

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I then set the environment variable `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings` but I then get the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'
```

What am I doing wrong? I have also tried running `django-admin runserver --settings=mysite.py`

Comment: have you tried `python manage.py runserver` ?

Comment: thanks @cagrias that worked! However, I'd really like to understand why using the django-admin command didn't work.

Comment: Remove that dot at the end of `django-admin startproject mysite .`.

Comment: @bencarter78 see my answer for details.

Comment: thanks @ipaleka but that just creates another directory which I don't want or need. The issue is just my lack of understanding between `django-admin` and `python manage.py`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is not set if you run `django-admin`. Instead of using `django-admin runserver`, you need to use `python manage.py runserver`. This is from the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-and-manage-py):

> In addition, manage.py is automatically created in each Django
>   project. It does the same thing as django-admin but also sets the
>   DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable so that it points to your
>   project’s settings.py file.

In other words, `django-admin` command does not know where your project's `settings.py` resides.